# Serre's Criterion for Normality & Depth of a Ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have a question about definition of $depth$ of a ring in view of the Serre's criterion for normality:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. $A$ fulfills the condition $S_k$ iff

$$ S_{k}:\operatorname {depth}A_{{{\mathfrak  {p}}}}\geq \inf\{k,\operatorname {ht}({\mathfrak  {p}})\} $$

for every prime ideal $\mathfrak  {p}$.

My question is quite simple: the $\operatorname {depth}A_{{{\mathfrak  {p}}}}$ of the localized ring $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is considered with respect to which ideal? Also $\mathfrak  {p}$?

I'm only familiar with with term "depth" as introduced here

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LE

Here we consider an ideal $I \subset A$ of a ring and a $A$-module $M$. Then $depth_I(M)$ with respect to $I$ is defined as the supremum of all lengths of $M$-regular sequences in $I$ (see def. in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LF).

The problem is with respect which ideal $I$  and a $A$-module $M$ is defined $$\operatorname {depth}A_{{{\mathfrak  {p}}}}\ ?$$

Intuitively I guess $I = \mathfrak{p}$ and $M = A_p$ as $A$-module? Is it true?

Comment: If R is a local ring then depth R is the depth of the maximal ideal.

Comment: @user26857: So here wrt $I = \mathfrak{p}$. But as $A$-module or $A_p$-module?

Comment: So here with respect to $I=pA_p$.

Comment: @user26857: And we interpret here $A_p$ as an $A$ or $A_p$ module? Or does it here for calculation of $depth(A_p)$ doen't make any difference?

Comment: In fact, it doesn't make any difference, but if you want consider $A_p$ as an $A_p$-module.

Comment: Do you know a good argument why here there doesn't make any difference to consider it as $A$ or $A_p$-module?

Comment: Every regular sequence in $A$ (contained in $p$) remains regular in $A_p$.